# How do I get the guild ID in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make some server-specific commands for a private bot but I can't figure out how to get the guild id into a state that I can use to compare. The bot's in a few private servers but the commands are basically inside jokes so they need to work in specific servers only.

My current code is this:

```
    if discord.Guild.id == 765623206925041675:
      await message.channel.send("Funny joke!")
    else:
      await message.channel.send("Disabled in this server.")
```

The command and responses are placeholders at the moment, just examples.

The code here always responded with the else statement, even when in the matching guild. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the class itself, not the instance. To get the guild ID

```py
guild_id = message.guild.id
```

Comment: That worked thanks! Still fairly new to the API so I'm learning as I go!

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def myCommand(ctx):
    if ctx.guild.id != 765623206925041675:
        await ctx.send('Disabled in this server.')
        return

    await ctx.send('Funny joke!')
```

If you're trying to do it in the `on_message` event, it'll look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild.id != 765623206925041675:
        await message.channel.send('Disabled in this server.')
        return

    await message.channel.send('Funny joke!')
    await client.process_commands(message)     # Important for commands to work
```